# What do you call the crack between the seating mattresses in a couch?

Tags: word-request

[image]

As you see in the picture, we have 3 mattresses and 2 cracks in the middle that extends from the upper area to the bottom area. What are these cracks called? Is there a specific word for it?

Comment: I don't know if there's a word for that gap, but at least in the US, I think what you refer to as "mattresses" would be more likely to be called "cushions"--either sofa cushions or couch cushions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specific name for this, but things that fall into these cracks are said to be *behind*, *beneath*, *under*, *between*, *in*, or *underneath* the cushions.

> If you're ever short of money remember there's always loose change **beneath** the sofa cushions. Always.

(Edit) If you do search for examples to see which of these might be more prevalent, try not to make your search too specific.  For example, I found this headline (among many others) from a search for "beneath the cushions":

> [Members Find Billions Beneath Pentagon Couch Cushions](https://www.rollcall.com/news/policy/members-find-billions-beneath-pentagon-couch-cushions)

this from "under the cushions":

> [Aretha Franklin's will discovered under couch cushions](https://consequenceofsound.net/2019/05/aretha-franklins-will-discovered-under-couch-cushions/)

and this from "between the cushions":

> [A Sofa That Encourages You To Lose Things Between the Cushions](https://gizmodo.com/a-sofa-that-encourages-you-to-lose-things-between-the-c-5911528)

Since all these seem to mean more or less the same thing, which you should use depends on which sounds best under the circumstances.

Comment: Google Books, ["loose change beneath the sofa cushions"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22loose+change+beneath+the+sofa+cushions%22&tbm=bks&source=lnt&tbs=sbd:1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjt6eeW1ZHjAhWXVRUIHV-ZBwQQpwUIIg&biw=1493&bih=745&dpr=1.2) : 0 hits. But ["loose change down the back of the sofa"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22loose+change+down+the+back+of+the+sofa%22&tbm=bks&source=lnt&tbs=sbd:1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjO3O6m1ZHjAhXkRxUIHYfsD3IQpwUIIg&biw=1493&bih=745&dpr=1.2) turns up in 4 different books (all from this century, somewhat surprisingly).

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I don't think you're specifically objecting to the answer, but I've edited it to address this. If you widen the search to more than "loose change" you find a wide variety of results.

Comment: You're quite right I wasn't *objecting* to your words here. In the context of *this* question they're fine. But I got here by following your ["duplicate link"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/216608/my-stuff-keeps-getting-stuck-between-the-little-space-backrest-and-where-you-si), so I was just thinking in terms of the idiomatic way to refer to things that have ***slipped into the sofa***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  https://lowres.cartooncollections.com/sofas-couches-sofa_cushions-guest-host-miscellaneous-CC66044_low.jpg