# My stuff keeps getting stuck between the little space (backrest and where you sit on the sofa)

Tags: word-usage

[image]

There is a little space between the backrest and cushion of the sofa (where people sit), and things might slip into that little region. So what will be a natural way to describe that?

> My things keep slipping into the sofa.
>
> ---

My question is different because the linked question was about "what's the crack called" But my question was about  "something fallen into it and expressing that idea naturally... "

Comment: I knew this sounded familiar:   Possible duplicate of [What do you call the crack between the seating mattresses in a couch?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/207938/what-do-you-call-the-crack-between-the-seating-mattresses-in-a-couch)

Answer (score 1):

There are *many, **many*** written examples of things being...

> [*lost **down the back of** the sofa*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22lost%20down%20the%20back%20of%20the%20sofa%22)

...and I'd say that's the most common phrasing (unless you're from a social class that sits on [***settees*** or ***couches***](https://www.sofa.com/inspiration-corner/why-do-we-call-it-a-sofa/), in which case substitute your preferred term).

Comment: When I was a kid, it was the "settee". That, I now find, marks me as no higher than mid-middle class; higher than that, it's "sofa", according to the _Daily Mail_.

Comment: And if someone is looking for something,  they is this the way it'll be expressed: "I guess it's down the back of the sofa."

Comment: And what about: "My sunglasses (or sunnies) went down the back of the sofa."

Answer (score 0):

Loose change gets behind or falls behind the cushions. [of a couch or sofa]

[behind the cushions](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&tbm=bks&ei=ytMYXaixEu29ggfnjJGAAg&q=%22loose%20change%22%20%2B%20sofa&oq=%22loose%20change%22%20%2B%20sofa&gs_l=psy-ab.3...7560.16271.0.16641.29.26.3.0.0.0.217.2706.15j9j1.25.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.19.2061...0j0i10k1j33i299k1.0.NQL7Ht_NE48)

You lose it there or find it there. [horizontal]

Or: stuff gets stuck in the space between the two parts of the back of the couch. [vertical]

I said "loose change" because typically, that's what is found there. It's easy to google.

Answer (score 0):

Brits might say "down the back of a sofa" It is often worth thrusting one's hand down the back (or side) of old sofas and armchairs. I once found some old (1920s) UK bank notes like that. They had a face value of a few pounds only, but they were in collectable condition and I sold them to an antique dealer for about 10 times face value. A good find in 1975. Also you often find coins and such things as tools (e.g. screwdrivers), knives (careful!), table cutlery, pens, etc.

[7 Weird Things Found Down the Back of Sofas](https://www.sofaworkshop.com/blog/fun/8-weird-things-found-back-sofas/)